# How to save last Emacs session time and hostname to a log file on quit/close

Tags: org-mode, quitting, logging

**Background / Problem:** I have 2 machines sharing a file directory using Google drive.  I edit the shared files using Emacs on both machines alternatively everyday.  I would like to make sure that at most one active Emacs session is running at a time to avoid sync conflict due to multiple active sessions with unsaved files.

**Idea:** I would like to make Emacs to save the time-stamp and hostname to some shared log file whenever I close it, so that I can check the log entry when I open Emacs on another machine next time.  That makes sure my previous Emacs sessions was closed and all files were saved and synced/up-to-date.

**Implementation:** I would like to add a function to [kill-emacs-hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Emacs.html) to append or replace time-stamp and hostname in a log file.  The log file can be a org-mode file with a heading "Last session close time", so that I can replace the old content (i.e., old time-stamp and hostname) under that heading in the function.  How can I do that?

Or: Is there any package provide the "last session time" logging for us?

Another question (please let me know if I should create a new question on stackexchange): We can [open an org-mode file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881245/how-to-open-an-org-mode-file-automatically-in-emacs) when starting Emacs.  Can we make sure a specific heading (in my case "Last session close time") is shown on startup?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer you are expecting, but:

If you are running on GNU/Linux in a GNOME environment, you could try the upcoming Emacs 26.1. Tramp offers a new method there, `gdrive`, which allows you to edit the file remotely on the Google drive. Something like

```
C-x C-f /gdrive:michael.albinus@gmail.com:/dir/to/file
```

Replace the account name with yours.

If you use an older Emacs, you could download the recent Tramp 2.3.2, which comes already with Google drive support.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following hook to append the timestamp to my startup file:

```
(setq my-startup-filename "~/Google Drive/startup.txt")
(add-hook
 'kill-emacs-hook
 (lambda ()
   (append-to-file (concat "\n" system-name " " (format-time-string "%a, %Y/%m/%d, %l:%M %p")) nil my-startup-filename)))
```